# Which features should be added for NER in search result snippets

Tags: cluster-analysis, information-retrieval, named-entity-recognition

I want to cluster queries by help of the snippets of the search engine results they are currently returning. While using the noun phrases in the snippet worked well for Google results I felt that I should try a different approach for bing snippets and hence was going for Named Entity Extraction.

I have identified the following entities that can be extracted as of now using standard tools:

1. Person Names
2. Organisation Names
3. Locations

But I think I should be extracting more entities. Could anyone help me out here to identify more entities that may be useful?

Answer (score 0):

This is an endless list, once you get to real data problems.

For example, *dates* are a common thing to extract. But for example *booking codes* such as airline tickets, or *tracking codes* such as parcels are something Google Mail already recognizes and extracts.

I don't think this is a very good question for a Q/A site. Plus, you may want to read more literature, and see what kind of data you can get - it clearly is *data-driven* what entities you want to extract. When analyzing log files, you might be interested in extracting host names, IPs, usernames and daemon/serivce names, for example.